# How to paginate a Word document from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-word

How to paginate a word document for example

if there are 10 pages:

page 1 of 10

Page 2 of 10 ...

if there are 15 pages

1 of 15 Page

2 of 15 ...

and so on to generate a dynamic number of pages

Comment: Elaborate on what `paginate` means.

Comment: What are you using? OpenXML? Word Automation?

Comment: You mean automate word so that it adds this in the footer or something? This feature already exists so coding a macro to make an easier job of adding the page numbers (if possible to even be easier) is the only task I can see that you might mean!?

Comment: @Hinek I'm drawing data into the document using html

Comment: If you are using Html then why not use CSS for pagination etc

Comment: @Alex but you ask for a Word document, not for HTML in the question. If it is HTML you are using, I agree with HatSoft, use CSS

Comment: I don't know how to use CSS for paging

Comment: Some code would be nice to see, if only to understand what you're talking about... (I'm not the OP, by the way...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer [How to paginate a Word document from c# with Open XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013773/how-to-paginate-a-word-document-from-c-sharp-with-open-xml?rq=1)
in more

if you can generate xml for it.

- Create a New Word Document,
- set Pagination into that.
- save the document as XML see tags for pagination. you might find something like footer1.xml