# How to get pagination of word document?

Tags: c#, xml

how to get pages of a word document? I want to make a xml file from docx(or doc) file in this format:

```
<Page No="1">
<text>Text of page 1 here</text>
<footnote>text of footnote here</footnote>
</Page>

<Page No="2">
<text>Text of page 2 here</text>
<footnote>text of footnote here</footnote>
</Page>
```

....
Thanks

Comment: I'm going to guess that you will have to show [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is very useful:
http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html

Answer (score 1):

refer [How to paginate a Word document from c# with Open XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013773/how-to-paginate-a-word-document-from-c-sharp-with-open-xml?rq=1)
in more

if you can generate xml for it.

- Create a New Word Document,
- set Pagination into that.
- save the document as XML see tags for pagination. you might find something like footer1.xml